# TFS Admin services

Tags: tfs

Are there any Team Foundation built-in services to help manage your project, team, access levels etc? I know there's a web front end but I have a requirement to bulk create projects and set them up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool called the TFS Team Project Manager which sounds like it's what you're looking for.

http://teamprojectmanager.codeplex.com/